# Embed Microsoft Word, Excel documents inside python desktop application using PyQt

Tags: python, windows, pyqt4, desktop-application, ole

I am trying to use python-oletools to embed MS word, Excel inside my PyQt Desktop Application. 
I am expecting something like how eclipse opens Word & Excel?
Is there any other way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how Eclipse does it, but [QAxContainer](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qaxcontainer.html) is how I would do it (assuming you're on Windows).